# How to programmatically append fields to node object when cloning with createDuplicate()

Tags: nodes, 9

I am trying to setup a custom module which copies values from a node whose content type is *A* to a node whose content type is *B*. For the most part, the content types have the same fields, but *B* has a few additional fields.

#### A

- Title (title)
- Body (body)
- Date (field_date_agenda)

#### B

- Title (title)
- Body (body)
- Date (field_date_agenda)
- Number of items (field_int_how_many)
- Reference to *A* (field_noderef_nta)

With `$cloned_node = $node->createDuplicate()` I am able to copy all the fields from *A*, as well as being able to change the content type  to *B*.
Since *A* doesn't have the extra fields attached to it, `createDuplicate()` won't copy them.

Now, what I would like to do is to programmatically add the other fields (which I will populate with some custom values) to `$cloned_node`. When these actions are completed, `$cloned_node->save()` will be used to finalize the cloning process.

Simply adding the value via `$cloned_node->set("field_int_how_many", $value)` doesn't seem to do the trick: A PHP error is thrown.

> InvalidArgumentException: Field field_int_how_many is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 587 of /home/username/domains/domainname.com/public_html/devsite/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/ContentEntityBase.php).

Does anyone have an idea how to add those extra fields to the cloned node?

Answer (score 3):

If the content type of `$node` is *A*, the content type of the node returned by `$node->createDuplicate()` is still *A*. That's why `$node->createDuplicate()->set("field_int_how_many", $value)` returns an error saying that *field_int_how_many* is an unknown field: Content type *A* doesn't have that field.

What you are trying to obtain isn't a clone of `$node`, but to copy the values from a node whose content type is *A* to a node whose content type is *B*.
For that, you need to create a new node, passing the values of the existing node field as values for the new node fields.

```php
$new_node = Node::create(
  'type' => 'B',
  'title' => $node->title,
  'body' => $node->body,
  'field_date_agenda' => $node->field_data_agenda,
  'field_int_how_many' => /* the value to assign to the field */
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and clear answer. I will give it a go.